# Associativity of the Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff operation on a Banach-Lie algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, banach-algebras, free-lie-algebras

Let $(\mathfrak{g}, [\cdot,\cdot]_\mathfrak{g}, \Vert \cdot \Vert_\mathfrak{g})$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach-Lie algebra, and let us define for any $a,b \in \mathfrak{g}$ the series
$$~ Z^\mathfrak{g} (a,b):= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}  \sum_{\substack{m_1+n_1>0\\ ... \\m_k+n_k>0}} \frac{[\overbrace{a,[...,[a}^{m_1}, \overbrace{[b,[...,[b}^{n_1}, [...[\overbrace{a,[...,[a}^{m_k},[\overbrace{b,[...,[b,b}^{n_k}]_\mathfrak{g}]_\mathfrak{g}...]_\mathfrak{g}...]_\mathfrak{g}}{m_1!n_1!...m_k!n_k! \sum_{i=1}^k (m_i+n_i)}.$$
If we consider the completion $\mathbb{Q}\langle \langle a,b,c \rangle \rangle$ of the free algebra generated by $a, b$ and $c$, and the completion $\mathcal{L}_\mathbb{Q}\langle \langle a,b,c \rangle \rangle$ of the corresponding free Lie algebra, where $[a,b]=ab-ba$ and so on, then we have $$Z(a,b):= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}  \sum_{\substack{m_1+n_1>0\\ ... \\m_k+n_k>0}} \frac{[\overbrace{a,[...,[a}^{m_1}, \overbrace{[b,[...,[b}^{n_1}, [...[\overbrace{a,[...,[a}^{m_k},[\overbrace{b,[...,[b,b}^{n_k}]]...]...]}{m_1!n_1!...m_k!n_k! \sum_{i=1}^k (m_i+n_i)}=\log(e^ae^b),$$
i.e. Dynkins extension of the Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff theorem, and it holds [(Dynkin 1950)](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=8399&option_lang=eng) that $$Z(Z(a,b),c)=Z(a,Z(b,c)).$$

Can we conclude that for any $a,b,c \in \mathfrak{g}$ such that $$Z^\mathfrak{g} (a,b),~ Z^\mathfrak{g} (b,c),~ Z^\mathfrak{g} (Z^\mathfrak{g} (a,b),c), ~ Z^\mathfrak{g} (a,Z^\mathfrak{g} (b,c))$$ converge in $\mathfrak{g}$, $Z^\mathfrak{g}$ can be seen as an associative operation, i.e.

$$Z^\mathfrak{g} (Z^\mathfrak{g} (a,b),c)=Z^\mathfrak{g} (a,Z^\mathfrak{g} (b,c))?$$ Note that $\mathfrak{g}$ is not necessarily an algebra, and thus $\log$ and $\exp$ are not defined in $\mathfrak{g}$, as neither is the commutator. The Lie bracket $[\cdot,\cdot]_\mathfrak{g}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ is not the commutator, as is the case in the free Lie algebra.

Comment: Is it not clear that, because the two formal infinite sums are equal, then their sums are equal whenever these sums are defined? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: The problem is, the Lie bracket in the Banach Lie algebra ist not the commutator, as is the case in the free Lie algebra.

Comment: Yes, but when you write $Z(Z(a,b),c)=Z(a,Z(b,c))$ I believe that this is an equation in the free Lie algebra. It is proved using the larger free associative algebra, but it is true in the Lie algebra.

Comment: The question (my question) is, how can you conclude that the identity holds in any Banach Lie algebra from its being true in the free Lie algebra?

Comment: (In my previous comment of course I should have written "completed free" instead of "free".) I repeat that if two power series have the same terms and they both converge then they have the same sum. Okay, these are "Lie series" rather than power series, so instead of a coefficient times a monomial each term has a coefficient times a basis element of a free Lie algebra, but it's the same idea.

Comment: In the completed free Lie-algebra Z(Z(a,b),c) and Z(a,Z(b,c)) have the same terms, but here convergence does not apply. On the other hand, in the Banach Lie algebra Z(Z(a,b),c) and Z(a,Z(b,c)) converge, but why should they have identical terms, or converge to the same element? It keeps eluding me how to use a universal property of the free Lie algebra to prove that Z(Z(a,b),c) and Z(a,Z(b,c)) have the same (limit) value in the Banach-Lie algebra.

Comment: How can we know e.g. that in the Banach-Lie algebra [a, [ b, [c, [a,....c]]...]]] - a is not zero? The point I am trying to make is, in the Banach-Lie algebra you cannot be certain that nested brackets of higher degree or combinations of them don't turn out  to be equal to brackets of a lower degreel, or can't you?

Comment: In the completion of the free Lie algebra an element, such as $Z(Z(a,b),c)$, is a formal expression $\sum_n x_n(a,b,c)$ where $x_n(a,b,c)$ is a homogeneous degree $n$ element of the free Lie algebra, i.e. a linear combination of nested bracket expressions of degree $n$ in the indeterminates $a,b,c$.

Comment: When you suppose that this converges for some $a,b,c$ in $\frak g$, you are supposing that the series of vectors in the Banach space $\sum_n Z(Z(a,b),c)$ converges to some vector in the Banach space. You know that in the completion of the free Lie algebra the element $Z(a,Z(b,c))$ is $\sum_n x_n(a,b,c)$ (the $x_n$s are the same as for $Z(Z(a,b),c)$). Therefore, when $a,b,c$ stand for elements of $\frak g$, the series of vectors $Z(a,Z(b,c))$ is term by term equal to the series of vectors $Z(Z(a,b),c)$.

Comment: So if the limit of partial sums exists for one series then it exists and is the same for the other series.